# If property at session not null or default value, run/print javascript Razor ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to print javascript when I accessing model from session and property value not empty at Razor?

This is my code:

```
@{ ARM.Models.LanIDModel lanIdModel = (LanIDModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["sessLanIDModel"]; }}


@if(lanIdModel.LanID!=0 && lanIdModel.Name != string.Empty &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lanIdModel.Email)){
           @Html.Raw("$('.input-switch-disabled').removeAttr('disabled');");
        }
```

And when I run on browser, I got this:

```
 @if(lanIdModel.LanID!=0 && lanIdModel.Name != string.Empty && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lanIdModel.Email)){
Line 98:            @Html.Raw("$('.input-switch-disabled').removeAttr('disabled');");
Line 99:         }
```

Is it able to do?

Comment: As the error you didn't show us is trying to tell you, `and` is not legal C#.  You're looking for `&&`.

Comment: Yes; you need to learn basic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your javascript in script tags.

```
@Html.Raw("<script>$('input-switch-disabled').removeAttr('disabled');</script>");
```